# WordPress Rating System

Tags: wordpress, rating

I am new to wordpress, and this is the first time i have built my own custom theme, and website using it.

I need a plugin that would allow my customers to rate our services, input there names, and email address' and from there show the administration and possibly the customers as well what they think of us. It isn't so much of a polling system rather a "Rate our services on a scale from 1-5" and then the system would average everyones rating.

Does anyone know of such plugin that exists?

thanks!
- Mike

Answer (score 1):

You could try this one...and just set up a service as a post.  Such as a post about your "computer service" or whatever you do.  And then in the post just use this plugin

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/gd-star-rating/